# How to set a where condition on multiplication of two columns in Sequelize?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm using Sequlize 5 with PostgreSQL. How do I generate the following query in sequelize?

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
WHERE col1*col2 = 50
AND col3 = 'somthing'
```

Comment: See here: https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-basics.html#advanced-queries-with-functions--not-just-columns-

Comment: Thank you! But how? Should I multiply two columns using sequelize.literal? @ChrisG

Comment: There's a bunch of dupes btw: https://www.google.com/search?q=sequelize+multiply+columns+site%3Astackoverflow.com

Comment: But none of them multiplied columns inside a where clause to set a condition on the result, they just selected the result. I had checked all of them before. @ChrisG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Chris G, I finally worked it out by using `Op.and`, `Sequelize.where` and `Sequelize.literal`. This is the solution I achieved:

```
MyTable.findAll({
   where: {
     [Op.and]: [
       Sequelize.where(Sequelize.literal('col1*col2'), 50),
       { col3: 'somethimg' },
     ],
   },
});
```